# How to take the label sizes in JUNG2.2 into account when generating a layout?

Tags: java, graph, jung

Is there a way to take (potential) different vertex sizes into account, when layouting a graph?

I've tried to mess around with setVertexShapeTransformer() of the BasicVisualizationServer but the drawing will not differ whatever size a vertex currently has. The issue is, that either edges are going trough a vertex or several vertexes are drawn over each other.

In my case the data model behind is a UML-Class-Diagramm like cyclic graph, if the vertexes are drawn over each other the readability of the overall drawing is quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

The existing `Layout` implementations do not take vertex size into account.  If you want them to do so, then you need to create an implementation to which you supply the VertexShapeTransformer (or some other means of determining the vertex size).

If you want to guarantee that vertex shapes will not overlap each other, your `Layout` would need to do some extra work to ensure that.  Ensuring that edges don't overlap vertices is a separate problem that you'd also need to invest in.

You might have at least limited success with adapting force-directed layouts like `FRLayout` so that the vertex repulsion force calculation would incorporate the size of the vertices.